# Where does UIWebView store HTML5 offline files?

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview, offline-caching

If I have some HTML5 offline content saved from a UIWebView in an iOS app, where does it get saved? Anywhere local that my app might have access to?

Answer (score 1):

I think in simulator you can find it in the /Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/..../Library/Caches/.../ApplicationCache.db

Answer (score 0):

I use [RNCachingURLProtocol](https://github.com/hborders/RNCachingURLProtocol) to view my offline content.